# Resque keeps using SQLite3 DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, capistrano, resque

I have a setup where the development DB is SQLite3 but for staging and production it is Postgres. I also have a resque task setup to basically asynchronously seed the database, but I keep getting this error:

.SQLite3::CantOpenException: unable to open database file: UPDATE "...."

I am not even using sqlite 3, but for some reason resque keeps using that DB.

There were two options to fix this on the resque site, but neither worked.

Adding this to the resque tasks

`

```
    namespace :resque do
       puts "Loading Rails environment for Resque"
       task :setup => :environment do
         ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.each { |klass|  klass.columns }
       end
    end
```

Or using this line to start resque:
QUEUE=file_serve rake environment resque:work

Any ideas why this is trying to use SQLite3? This does work fine when just running rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=staging

Comment: check your `database.yml` file

Comment: It is set properly for staging, and it works when I do a regular rake db:seed. When I change the database.yml file to all postgres (including for development), it works fine, but that is a hack/short term fix.

Comment: @JustinTime how did u started resque did you gave `RAILS_ENV=staging` at time of starting

Comment: No, I ran rake environment and I assumed it would load the executing rails environment.